# Does scala-pickling work with Scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, scala-pickling

Is there any way to use scala-pickling with scala 2.11 yet?

I've tried the only scala-pickling_2.11 artifact at the sonatype repository but it doesn't seem to work. I get the message:

Error:(26, 43) can't expand macros compiled by previous versions of Scala

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use scala-pickling with higher versions of scala but there is [boopickle](https://github.com/suzaku-io/boopickle) which might help you out.

You can easily import it into an sbt project with

```
libraryDependencies += "io.suzaku" %% "boopickle" % "1.3.2"
```

and this works with scala version 2.13.3 at least.